# Denoising audio playback with pyaudio

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I'm writing a vocoder in Python for Raspberry Pi, something to change voice to be unrecognizable. I record audio and do a playback in real time with callback function - it works. Now I need to denoise the input, represented as a Numpy array (NOT .wav file like most tutorials and posts on SO do!). I've tried using several audio denoisers, but in particular this one: https://pypi.org/project/noisereduce/ (tutorial: https://timsainburg.com/noise-reduction-python.html, source: https://github.com/timsainb/noisereduce). It does not work for me.
My main.py:

```
from copy import copy
import numpy as np
import pyaudio as pa
import time
import noisereduce as nr

p = pa.PyAudio()

FORMAT = pa.paFloat32
NP_FORMAT = np.float32
CHANNELS = 2
CHUNK = 1024
RATE = int(p.get_default_input_device_info()['defaultSampleRate'])
NOISE_SAMPLE = None


# function for manipulating input data
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    data = copy(np.frombuffer(in_data))  # copy, since original is read-only

    # here everything is ok for first time
    # print("X")
    out_data = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=data, noise_clip=NOISE_SAMPLE)
    # print("Y")
    # I get here only once

    return out_data, pa.paContinue


def get_noise():
    audio = pa.PyAudio()
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    frames = []
    RECORD_SECONDS = 1
    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(np.frombuffer(data))

    # stop Recording
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    return np.array(frames, dtype=NP_FORMAT).flatten()


def main():
    global NOISE_SAMPLE
    NOISE_SAMPLE = get_noise()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    rate=RATE,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    input=True,
                    output=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                    stream_callback=callback)

    stream.start_stream()

    # main input loop
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I record noise sample for 1 second and then go into infinite record-playback loop, where I want to denoise the input and get it to output. It works only once for some reason: I get "X" and "Y" printed out once, after a long time (why?), and program goes on and on, but does not enter callback function any more. Any ideas why? Any suggestions, other libraries easier to use here etc. are welcome.